# Hide <i> in mobile version

Tags: responsive-design

I have the following code and can't seem to figure out how to hide the italic subtext that's between "i" element in mobile mode only. Essentially I want just the "Home" to display in mobile. `

```
<div class="nav-container">   
       <nav>         
        <ul class="nav" id="nav">
         <li><a href="#home" class="nav-active"> <span>Home</span><i>Welcome to</br> our site</i></a></li>
          <li> <a href="#about"><span>About</span><i>What We</br>Do</i></a> </li> etc..
```

i {visibility: hidden;} works all the time, but I only need it during mobile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    i { display: none; }
}
```

That will hide `<i>` elements on any screen size less than 768 pixels wide.

Note that `display: none` will essentially remove it from the page flow whereas `visibility: hidden` just makes it invisible but it is still part of the page flow.

Comment: for some reason "display: none" doesn't work, but "visibility: hidden" does at least hide it. You are right from a page flow aspect that display: none would be better, if it worked. Not sure why it's not.

Comment: that's odd. is there some css rule with higher specificity interfering?  something like `body i { display: inline }` or similar?

Comment: Yes actually I believe    `.post-tags i {
 display: inline-table;` is probably interfering but can't be changed due to formatting.

Comment: yes, that's more specific. are you saying you can't overwrite it with a more specific rule due to layout issues?  you can always make an exception for `.post-tags i` and put `display: none` on all other `<i>` elements - e.g. inside the media query above try `html body i { display: none; }` and `html body .post-tags i { display: inline-table; visibility: hidden; }`

Comment: Yes, due to layout issues. I'll try your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: hmm. No such luck. Here's a visual of what i'm trying to do. where this image !(http://i1231.photobucket.com/albums/ee509/jonaberr/ScreenShot2013-07-30at14227PM_zps6dac7ee9.png). shows the nav bar and the subtext. I just want the main pages titles.

Comment: try `#nav li a i { display: none; }` and if that doesn't do it, please make a JSFiddle that recreates the problem!

Comment: You could check that it is in fact an override issue but putting `i { display:none !important;` and seeing if that hides it. If it does it means that somewhere in your stylesheets you're specifying a more specific style than just `i`, or `.post-tags i`. It would be a good way to double check that, that is the issue. It's not necessarily a fix (although it may fix it), but it will help address the issue

Comment: Rob's advice does indeed hide the `<i>` element, but when using the @media query it resurfaces on the mobile menu. It hides the ~<i>` element on the desktop and tablet verion under 786px, but re-appears on mobile dropdown menu. Thanks for all of the help so far.